# Live DVD crashes

Tags: 14.04

When I try 14.04 from a live DVD within seconds of the desktop stabilising it crashes to a pattern of coloured diagonal lines without any action from me. I have re-downloaded and burned the DVD several times and it is quite consistent. Is this a "funny" with the live DVD, or will installed 14.04 also crash?

Asrock ALiveNF6G
AMD dual core 64 bit
1 G RAM.

Comment: Did anything help?

Answer (score 0):

The disc can check itself for defects:
[image]

Answer (score 0):

When booting, press "F6 Other Options" and check "nomodeset".
[image]

Then boot as usual.